# How do I cancel another build when a new build starts in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I want to cancel a build for A when a new build for B starts. How do I do that using jenkins?

Is there a plugin that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there is no automated solution to stopping builds that are currently building. However it's not a bad idea to let the build finish, if it fails you will at least know why and where the error is. After that build finished your newest build in the que will be build.

However there is a manual way of stopping a build that is currently ongoing. Simply open the project and click on red cross next to the build that is running. Below a picture of how it looks for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using HTTP request in a shell step, e.g.:

```
curl http://$JENKINS_URL/job/A/lastBuild/stop
```

or using Groovy system build step, e.g.:

```
job = Jenkins.instance.getItem('A')
for (build in job.builds) {
    if (build.isBuilding()) {
        build.doStop();
    }
}
```

Comment: The first option tells me I need to be authenticated to get that done

Comment: Yes, @Brown, it is using the external API so naturally you need to authenticate if you have security enabled in Jenkins. At simplest it is enough just add option `--user user:password` to the curl command.